# Formal proof for this predicate logic problem.

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logic, predicate-logic

So Q(x) is a predicate in some domain of discourse. I am given $\neg$($\forall$y Q(y)) and I want to make a formal proof that shows that $\exists$x (Q(x) $\rightarrow$ $\forall$y Q(y)) follows from it. How would one approach it?

I tried moving the negation all the way to the center with De Morgans. Then I did Elim $\exists$ for some special c that satisfies Q. Then I did Intro $\exists$ to introduce x. I am not sure where to go from there.

Comment: See the proof you're looking for below

Answer (score 0):

You say:

> Then I did Elim $\exists$ for some special c that satisfies Q.

That's not right. If you moved the negation inside, you should have gotten $\exists y\  \color{red}{\neg} Q(y)$. So, your special $c$ should *not* have property $Q$.

In fact, with $\neg Q(c)$, you should be able to to prove $Q(c) \to \forall y \ Q(y)$, because the antecedent of that conditional is false, and so the conditional has to be true. So by $\exists$ Intro, you're there.

If you want help with the xact formalization of that, you'll need to let us know how exactly your rules are formally defined, since there are many different formalization.  But, I think with the above proof sketch, you should be able to do it.

Comment: Oh, so I had $\neg$ Q(c) after. That however is true, for some special c that satisfies that. I could do intro $\vee$ to get $\neg$ Q(c) $\vee$ $\forall$y Q(y), then use law of implication? I believe then I could do intro $\exists$? Does that sound right?

Comment: @uwuwuuwuwuw If you have all those rules, then yes, that works.

Answer (score 0):

$\neg \forall y Q(y)$

$\exists y \neg Q(y)$ by Demorgan's Law for Quantifers

$\neg Q(a)$ by existential instantiation

$\neg Q(a) \vee Q(y)$ by disjunction introduction

$Q(a) \rightarrow Q(y)$ by implication rule

$\forall y (Q(a) \rightarrow Q(y))$ by universal generalization

$Q(a) \rightarrow \forall y Q(y)$ by null quantification

$\exists x (Q(x) \rightarrow \forall y Q(y))$ by existential generalization